# Adding tel: links using Redactor

Tags: redactor

Is there a way to add `tel:` links in the Redactor WYSIWYG?
I tried `Link` > `Insert link` to enter `tel:+43123456789` as URL,
but all I got was `<a>+43123456789</a>`. The href is missing.

Comment: I believe you need to turn off the "Purify HTML" or the "Clean up HTML" option, but I forget which - my money's on purify, though.

Comment: Redactor v1.2.2 changelog: [Improved] "tel:" protocol support in URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your Rich Text field settings, if you uncheck the "Purify HTML?" option, the `tel:` reference will stay in tact.